# Static function in C++

Tags: c++

I came up with a question when studying C++. It is about the static function.
In this header file, I created a static function.

```
using namespace std;
class Date
{
public:
    int dd, mm, yy;
public:
    //Date();
    Date(int d, int m, int y);
    static bool LeapYear(Date t);
};
```

And in this source file, I have defined the function

```
{
    if ((t.yy % 400 == 0) || (t.yy % 4 == 0) && (t.yy % 100 != 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

It is said that static function cannot get access to non-static members. But when I put an object into that function, it is still working. Can anyone explain this for me? Thank you!

Comment: "static function cannot get access to non-static members" is a weird and confusing statement. The difference between static and non-static function is simply that a non-static function is attached to implicit `this` object. And static function is not attached to anything.

Comment: Defining a function as `static` in c++ means it can be accessed without creating an instance of the class therefore it cannot access the member variables because it is not attached to `this` as mentioned by @freakish

Comment: Credits to you as well, @Ahmn21!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between static and non-static member functions is that when you call a non-static member function a pointer to the class instance is implicitly passed as the first argument (a **this** pointer). You need an instance of a class (an object) to call the non-static member function. Thus a member function is granted access to the members of the class instance.

On the contrary, static members and static member functions do not belong to the class instance, they are just part of class definition. That is why they can't access any non-static class members. That is also the reason static function can't be marked as const, because there are no instances they can modify.

```
class Date
{
public:
    int dd, mm, yy;

public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y);

    // static function
    // can't be marked const because it makes no sense
    static bool LeapYear(Date t) /*const*/ {
        if ((t.yy % 400 == 0) || (t.yy % 4 == 0) && (t.yy % 100 != 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;  
    }
    
    // member function - has access to this and thus to any non-static member of the instance
    // marked const because it doesn't change the instance
    bool isLeap() const {
        if ((/*this->*/yy % 400 == 0) || (yy % 4 == 0) && (yy % 100 != 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;  
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it!